# org.mapdb and maven2 trouble

Tags: java, maven, mapdb

I'm new to Maven. I'm trying to add a reference to org.mapdb in my java/maven2 pom.xml file, but maven seems unable to download mapdb artifact from remote repository.

What I've done: 
First thing: configured remote maven repository in settings.xml

Second: configured proxy settings for maven

Third: added the following lines to my POM file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapdb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapdb</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
    <type>bundle</type>
</dependency>
```

I'm pretty sure proxy and repository-related data are ok: I can download any other dependency in my project, e.g org.osgi.core or junit.

Build fails with following message:

```
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mapdb/mapdb/3.0.4/mapdb-3.0.4.bundle
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.mapdb:mapdb:bundle:3.0.4' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[INFO]     ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO]     ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Missing:
----------
1) org.mapdb:mapdb:bundle:3.0.4

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
  mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.mapdb -DartifactId=mapdb -Dversion=3.0.4 -Dpackaging=bundle -Dfile=/path/to/file

   Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
  mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.mapdb -DartifactId=mapdb -Dversion=3.0.4 -Dpackaging=bundle -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
1) com.sirti.NOC.acc_gw:DB_writer:jar:0.0
2) org.mapdb:mapdb:bundle:3.0.4

 ----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
  com.sirti.NOC.acc_gw:DB_writer:jar:0.0

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

I've already tried to manually browse repository, and I've seen mapdb jar in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mapdb/mapdb/3.0.4/

Of course, I could manually download and install jar, but what's the point in using maven, if I have to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've been able to download mapdb package.

Only had to remove

```
<type>bundle</type>
```

tag from dependency declaration.